# Can Akka actor drop messages from its mailbox if needed?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

For example, if I want to remove redundant messages from the queue - so that when actor recieves `Connect` message, it should inspect it's mailbox and remove other `Connect` messages, in order to do only one connect instead of several.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213032/hard-restart-directive-in-akka

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can configure the actors dispatcher to have any mailbox of your choice, so if you implement such a mailbox, you can use that, see the following section of the documentation: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.1/scala/dispatchers.html#Mailboxes

Comment: So the idea would be to create an extension of some standard mailbox, that would inspect itself on each new message, and drop it if there's already the same message in the mailbox?