# How to send message from Supervisor to Actor once Actor restarts?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-supervision

**Requirement?**
- There has to be a long running process(daemon) that should run forever
- In case of any exceptions, it should be restarted, but if it fails again twice, no restart efforts should be taken

**Problem I face?**
- The actor is restarted but no message sent again

**What I have?**

***Main Class***

```
package com.learner.ahka.runforever

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object RaceEvent extends App {
  val config = ConfigFactory.parseString( """
    akka.loglevel = "DEBUG"
    akka.actor.debug {
      receive = on
      lifecycle = on
    }
                                          """)
  val system = ActorSystem.create("race", config)
  val coach = system.actorOf(Coach.props(), "coach")
  coach ! GetSetGo
}
```

***Supervisor***

```
package com.learner.ahka.runforever

import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.{Escalate, Restart}
import akka.actor._
import akka.event.LoggingReceive

import scala.concurrent.duration._

case object GetSetGo

object Coach {
  def props(): Props = Props[Coach];
}

class Coach() extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  val runner = context.actorOf(Runner.props(new Marathon), "runner")

  override def supervisorStrategy: SupervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 2, withinTimeRange = 5 seconds) {
    case _: RuntimeException => Restart
  }

  override def receive = LoggingReceive {
    case GetSetGo => runner ! GoForIt
  }
}
```

***Actor***

```
package com.learner.ahka.runforever

import akka.actor.Status.Failure
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, Props}
import akka.event.LoggingReceive
import akka.pattern.pipe

object Runner {
  def props(race: Race) = Props(classOf[Runner], race)
}

class Runner(race: Race) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  import context.dispatcher

  override def receive: Receive = LoggingReceive {
    case GoForIt => race.start pipeTo self
    case Failure(throwable) => throw throwable
  }
}
```

***Actual work***

```
package com.learner.ahka.runforever

import scala.concurrent.Future

case object GoForIt

trait Race {
  def start: Future[Any]
}

class Marathon extends Race {

  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  override def start: Future[Any] = future

  val future = Future {
    for (i <- 1 to 3) {
      println("I am a Marathon Runner!")
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("MarathonRunner is tired")
  }
}
```

*Logs*

```
[DEBUG] [05/30/2015 16:03:35.696] [main] [EventStream(akka://race)] logger log1-Logging$DefaultLogger started
[DEBUG] [05/30/2015 16:03:35.698] [main] [EventStream(akka://race)] Default Loggers started
[DEBUG] [05/30/2015 16:03:35.704] [race-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://race/system] now supervising Actor[akka://race/system/deadLetterListener#-1391310385]
[DEBUG] [05/30/2015 16:03:35.706] [race-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://race/system/deadLetterListener] started (akka.event.DeadLetterListener@191ba186)
[DEBUG] [05/30/2015 16:03:35.710] [race-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://race/user] now supervising Actor[akka://race/user/coach#-1161587711]
I am a Marathon Runner!
[DEBUG] [05/30/2015 16:03:35.722] [race-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://race/user/coach] started (com.learner.ahka.runforever.Coach@66f0f319)
[DEBUG] [05/30/2015 16:03:35.722] [race-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://race/user/coach/runner] started (com.learner.ahka.runforever.Runner@72f67980)
[DEBUG] [05/30/2015 16:03:35.723] [race-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://race/user/coach] now supervising Actor[akka://race/user/coach/runner#755574648]
[DEBUG] [05/30/2015 16:03:35.723] [race-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://race/user/coach] received handled message GetSetGo
[DEBUG] [05/30/2015 16:03:35.725] [race-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://race/user/coach/runner] received handled message GoForIt
I am a Marathon Runner!
I am a Marathon Runner!
[DEBUG] [05/30/2015 16:03:38.739] [race-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://race/user/coach/runner] received handled message Failure(java.lang.RuntimeException: MarathonRunner is tired)
[ERROR] [05/30/2015 16:03:38.752] [race-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://race/user/coach/runner] MarathonRunner is tired
java.lang.RuntimeException: MarathonRunner is tired
    at com.learner.ahka.runforever.Marathon$$anonfun$1.apply(Race.scala:22)
    at com.learner.ahka.runforever.Marathon$$anonfun$1.apply(Race.scala:17)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

[DEBUG] [05/30/2015 16:03:38.753] [race-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://race/user/coach/runner] restarting
[DEBUG] [05/30/2015 16:03:38.755] [race-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://race/user/coach/runner] restarted
```

**UPDATE**
If I don't delegate to `Future`, everything works as expected, even in case of restart, but when delegated to `Future`, `Future` does not get executed in case of actor `restart`. See [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/akka-user/P_vMC74ZfGY/YR3PzG4PoOsJ)

Answer (score 1):

You could override the postRestart method to send a message back to the parent to notify it of the restart, then watch for that new message type in the parent and respond accordingly. If `context.parent` won't work happily for that purpose (I tend not to rely on it), then have the Coach actor pass it's `self` actor reference as a new constructor parameter when instantiating the `Runner`.

Comment: I tried that, the `SupervisorStrategy` works well, but message is not executed again. here is the link for my changes http://pastebin.com/cihYJd9L

Comment: Your code looks OK to me, so I presume there is something else we're overlooking (eg. need to flush the message queue on restart, perhaps?).

Comment: you mean clear the mailbox? That seems not possible with `Restart`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218937/can-akka-actor-drop-messages-from-its-mailbox-if-needed

Comment: I just realized that the supervision is working correctly and print statements are also coming correctly as per what needed, but future is not executed. See http://pastebin.com/E6TV4W25.  BTW, thanks a lot for helping, very much appreciated

Comment: and if I don't delegate to `Future` rather do it in the `Actor` itself, things seem to work http://pastebin.com/tcaLWVLT. Something with `Future` that I do not understand

Answer (score 1):

It is not well known, but you can access sender() from the supervisorStrategy. This means that you can easily identify the actor that you are going to restart (sender() will point to the ActorRef that is currently being decided on). This is completely safe.